# Python modules: functions calling each other

Tags: python, python-import, execfile

I have got myself very confused.  I have a set of python functions, all of which I've bunged together in a file called (let's say) `useful.py`.  I can then read the module into my ipython with

```
 import useful as uf
```

and then I can access individual functions with

```
 uf.meaning_of_life()
```

and so on.  Standard stuff.

However - some functions in this file call on other functions.  I can call a single function any time with `uf.`, but what about functions which call each other?  If a function called `eat` makes reference to another function called `chew`, how does `eat` know where to find `chew`?  I can call both as `uf.eat` and `uf.chew`.

I can ignore all of this by simply doing `execfile('useful.py')` which works perfectly well, but I would like to get more of a handle on the module system.

Currently when I use `import` my attempt to use my functions produces errors; when I use `execfile` everything works fine.

I appreciate that this might be construed as very much a beginners question, but I am coming to Python from a Matlab background, and my natural inclination is to use `execfile`.  Pointers to information would be very welcome.

Comment: `eat` and `chew` being functions in the same module can refer to each other by their unqualified names `eat` and `chew`.

Comment: If you really must import everything in 'useful.py' into the namespace of your current python module, `from useful import *` will import everything except names prefixed with '_'.  Then they can be accessed from the current module as `chew` rather than `uf.chew`.  This practice is generally frowned on, because you suddenly end up not knowing what names are already defined.

Comment: Incidentally, what error is coming up?  And what's wrong with using `uf.chew`?

Comment: I'll see if I can provide a clearer explanation of my issues, but as it's currently 1.30am I think I might get some sleep first!  Thank you for all your help and advice so far.

Answer (score 7):

What you need to understand first in order to get what's happening is that every module is its own local namespace.

If you have a module like this:

```
def chew():
    print('chewing')

def eat():
    print('eating')
    chew()
```

Isn't it obvious that `eat` can call `chew` without any problems? They're defined at the same level, in the global (module) scope, so clearly they can see each other.

Now we do the following in *another* module:

```
import useful as uf

uf.eat()
```

In order to access `chew`, we need to write `uf.chew`, the same way we have typed `uf.eat`.
We need to do this because *we are in another module*. In order for us to do any of that we have had to `import useful`, so that our module knows of it.  Our knowledge of the `useful` module is that its contents are added to the `uf` name.

That is *our* point of view.  But the `useful` module *knows everything about itself*. Nothing has changed there, it doesn't need to import itself to access its contents, and it doesn't know *anything* about *other* modules that it has not `import`ed itself.

So to answer, *`eat` knows how to find `chew` because they are in the same module*, and therefore in the same *scope*.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for your clear explanation.  So let me get this clear: eat() can happily access chew() because they're in the same module, but from my point of view I can only access each of them as uf.eat() and uf.chew().  That makes sense.  However, the fact remains that if I use import then some of the functions simply don't work, but if I read the file with execfile they all work perfectly.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: It's likely that you have done something wrong unadvertely in your module. If yould post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in your question, I might be able to help you with it.

Comment: I've put a file up at https://docs.google.com/document/d/12P_qDqbDikSFuNilCbiNwPxbJAH8-6NtXmfTaFUnAe0/edit?usp=sharing which contains a brief explanation, and the offending code.  Many thanks!

Comment: @Alasdair That is not a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). I've tried to run it a few times and I can't reproduce your problem.  Your current question is an obvious case of the (XY problem)[http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem] and the real question might be better suiten on (Code Review)[http://codereview.stackexchange.com/].

Comment: Ah, well - this is getting into territory way beyond my limited knowledge.  But thank you for your time and advice!  I'll keep plugging away, and at the worst I can always fall back on 'execfile'.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly its advisable to use from somefile import definition as something let me use your function definitions to give you a clear picture. I will write simple functions to eat and chew. where chew will references eat.

useful.py

```
def eat():
    print 'Eaten'

def chew():
    eat()
```

main File.py code

```
from useful import chew as uf

uf()
```

By calling uf alias for chew function which references the eat function. Welcome to python.

Comment: Unless you're only using a single (or a few) functions with very obvious names or, or a class of the same name as the module, doing a `import useful` is ok as it imports *a single name* under which every function exists instead of polluting the current namespace.  This answer is also *not really* an answer to the original question (unless I got it wrong).